# Foreign Key In MySQL using Yii

Tags: mysql, yii, relational-database

I have the database just like this

```
==== Invoices ====
id
customer_id
description

==== Customers ===
id
firstname
lastname
```

Now I have made the relation in between models just like this. In Invoices models the relation is as like this

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'customer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Customer', 'customer_id')
    );
}
```

In customer model the relation is just like this

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
      'invoice' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Invoices','customer_id')
    );
}
```

Now as my relation is defined one customer has many invoices and the invoice is belongs to the customer.

Now I made multimodel and loaded the Customer model into Invoice model just like this.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Invoices;
    $customers = new Customers;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Invoices'],$_POST['Customers']))
    {
      $model->attributes = $_POST['Invoices'];
      $customers->attributes = $_POST['Customers'];
      $valid = $model->validate();
      $valid = $customers->validate();
      if($valid)
      {
        $model->save(false);
        $customers->id = $model->customer_id;
        $customers->save(false);
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'customers'=>$customers,
    ));
}
```

Here everything is okay. I can insert the data for both models easily. But my problem comes here in the way that when I am inserting data from Invoice multimodel the foreign key id is not changing. It is showing zero every time. Can some one tell me where I am wrong.

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are overriding the customer's primary key with the invoice's foreign key. I do not say that's not correct that way (maybe in your scenario it makes sense).

Let me explain what you are doing in that code:

- First, you create new instances of two models, Invoices and Customers. Yii understands that as "they wish to insert new items in the database".
- Then, you check if there are the items coming from an ajax form. If true, then,
- You populate Invoices (defined as `$model`. I'd change it to `$invoice`, in case you need to edit and understand it further).
- You also popupulate the customer's information, overriding the `$valid` value (so, you don't know if invoice is actually valid).
- If valid (remember you're only validating customer's information), do,
- Save the invoice
- Override customer's id with invoice's foreing key to customer.
- Save the customer, and redirect.

Now, what I got from that:

- `$valid` doesn't work as expected: I'd change that to an incremental assignment.
- You may not be passing a `customer_id` coming from the ajax form. Foreing keys are integers, and so if not defined within a model, it becomes 0 or `NULL`.
- You are always passing id = 0 / `NULL` to Customer's model, so it would probably warn you when validating. However, you are using `save(false)`, which means it doesn't pre-validate on save, so you never know it doesn't work.

So, according to this:

```
  public function actionCreate()
  {
    $invoice = new Invoices;
    $customers = new Customers;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($invoice);

    if (isset($_POST['Invoices'],$_POST['Customers']))
    {
      $invoice->attributes = $_POST['Invoices'];
      $customers->attributes = $_POST['Customers'];
      $valid = true; /* expect it is always valid */
      $valid &= $invoice->validate(); /* if $invoice is not valid, $valid will be false (true&false = false) */
      $valid &= $customers->validate(); /* same as the above line */
      if($valid)
      {
        $customers->save(); /* First save customers. It's the Foreign item */
        $invoice->customer_id = $customers->getPrimaryKey(); /* new instances use getPrimaryKey() to get its id */
        $invoice->save(); /* Save invoice AFTER getting customer's primary key */
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$invoice->id));
      }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'invoice'=>$invoice,
      'customers'=>$customers,
    ));
  }
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Could you show us any error? You can even post any errors coming from $invoice->getErrors() and $customers->getErrors() (after validate() or save()). Also, I edited the code, as I forgot to change `model` to `invoice` in the render method.

Comment: Ya I have made the necessary changes that you have done here..But its not working. Not showing any errors.Just the Foreign Key is not updating all the data are doing easily save.

Comment: Forgive me, I found some more places where I left $model instead of $invoice. Avoid using `save(false)` (use `save()` instead) and print getErrors(), even if it's empty. Also, do a `var_dump($_POST)` and check everything is being received properly. Finally, print $customers->getPrimaryKey() too. If it hasn't got a valid number, check that the customer is being correctly saved by looking at the database.

Comment: Thanks Kor..finally it worked. But there is one thing in my doubt.Why to use save() instead save(false).You know when I used only save() it showed an error but when I used save(false) it worked.Can you clear my doubt?BTW thanks for your help.

Comment: save(false) stands by "save this model to database WITHOUT validating". Validation comes from your Customers (or Invoices, maybe both) model's rules(). I solved it plenty of times by looking at what is required and what is not. If do not put into the model an attribute that is required, validation fails. It may also be due to max lengths (Customers->firstname could be maxlength=10, but you passed a name with 11 letters). MySQL would just truncate the text, but Yii fails the validation. So, I recommend you to double check the rules function within the model. Tell us how you finally solved it =)

Answer (score 0):

Please you need to understand a clear scenerio here. why would you use 
if($valid)
      {
        $model->save(false);
        $customers->id = $model->customer_id;
        $customers->save(false);
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }

$model->save(false); tells model that if this record is not save(), the it shoud set the $customers->id = $model->customer_id;

This will only return false because. I do rather prefer if you call ( $customers->id = $model->customer_id;) before the $model->save();

REMEMBER, if you need to check if Save() returns true, then set it to $model->save(true)